# How do I display folder and file details in Precise Pangolin's file manager?

Tags: filemanager

I'd like to display file and folder details in the file manager, but I can't find any display options for it; it currently shows just icons and names for folders and files. I'm using Precise Pangolin.

Comment: Watch out! Precise Pangolin will reach the end of its life in April this year.

Comment: Thanks, for the heads-up, arochester; I'll install the latest version after I've finished my file copying work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select View->List in Nautilus' menu, or hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+2.

In case you wish to have different columns shown, adjust the settings under 
 Preferences->List Columns.

Comment: I should add, for complete newbies like me, that the menus for the file manager (AKA Nautilus) are not in the file manager itself; they're in the gray bar at the very top of the screen that shows the time at its right end. Mouse over it, and the menus appear.